# Swift: synchronise CoreData object in background

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency

I need to upload a `CoreData` object to the API server in background. To do that I create a new private context as a child of the main context and do `perform()` on it. I use this context to get a JSON data from the object and to write some data to the object after uploading.

It seems like all works fine but I have some doubts.

Below is a simple example which shows the case. Does the context have some strong reference in the second function? Should I keep some strong reference to my new context somewhere?

```
// ViewController.swift
func uploadObject(_ currentObject: MyManagedObject) {
    // we are in the main thread, go to another thread
    let objectId = currentObject.objectID
    let context = getNewPrivateContext()    // child context of the main context
    context.perform {
        if let object = context.object(with: objectId) as? MyManagedObject {
            SyncManager.shared.uploadObject(_ object: object, completion: {
                // ... update UI
            })
        }
    }
}

// SyncManager.swift
func uploadObject(_ object: MyManagedObject, completion: ()->()) {
    // does the context has some strong reference here?
    guard let context = object.managedObjectContext { completion(); return }

    let params = getJson(with: object)
    // ... prepare url, headers
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON( completionHandler: { (response) in
            // ... parse the response
            context.perform {
                // ... write some data to the Core Data and save the context
                completion()
            }
        })
}
```

EDIT

Also my doubts are supported by one lldb issue:

```
(lldb) po context
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'context'
context
^~~~~~~
```

Comment: All looks good to me

Comment: Be aware that `context.object(with: objectId)` will generate a new object for you. You probably want `existingObject(with:)`

Answer (score 0):

It is a strong reference, but it is unsafe, meaning if the receiver(the object) is removed from it's context, it will return nil.

Just my opinion, I would use a `if let` statement instead of a guard:

```
func uploadObject(_ object: MyManagedObject, completion: ()->()) {
    // does the context has some strong reference here?
    if let context = object.managedObjectContext {

        let params = getJson(with: object)
        // ... prepare url, headers
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON( completionHandler: { (response) in
            // ... parse the response
            context.perform {
                // ... write some data to the Core Data and save the context
                completion()
            }
        })
    } else {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing `guard` to `if let` doesn't make sense. This just adds unnecessary  nesting of the code.

Comment: Sorry about that then :), well that was the only issue I seen...you are saving the privateMOC, which will push it's changes to its parent MOC...I didn't mean it was better, just two different ways to handle optionals.  Both ways that block of code is only ran if `context` is set

Comment: Actually, your `context` may be getting released with the change of scope.  Set breakpoints, and run `po context.userInfo` or `po context.persistentStoreCoordinator`.  I normally hold two MOC objects in my  coordinator class, one main and one private to parse data/write data in the background.  I say it is a strong reference because looking at the property in Apple's object reference lists it as simply `var` which should make it strong, as long as the documentation is correct.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Now I know that `managedObjectContext` is strong but unsafe property. I thought it's weak property. ) Please look at my edit of the post. I can't do `po context` for some reason.